# Pagination inside of a edit page

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I looked all over for this and could not find the answer

I have two custom post types one is named 'venues' and the other is 'events' every 'venue' has multiple 'events' relating to it. I have a custom metabox inside of venue to display all related events, sometimes there is hundreds of events in this metabox is there a way to paginate inside of this metabox that lives on the custom post type venue. I really just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: use [AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to populate and paginate the contents.

Comment: So do you think the standard $paged pagination wont work?

Comment: The answer to "if this is possible" is nearly universally yes. It's another matter how complicated it is. How _is_ your metabox implemented? How do you imagine pagination UI will work? What issues do you see with implementing it?